# Good checksum to speed up searches

Tags: checksum, crc32

I want to speed up the search of my application by creating an checksum index of my strings.

Is CRC32 good enough? I'm not using it for security. Just as a way to represent a string as a hashed(Integer/Long) index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a hash code, not a checksum. CRC32 should be fine though, but not very efficient. Also have a look at Adler32 (used by zlib), which is faster to calculate.

See also [Hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)

Comment: See my reply above. This should suit me quite well.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to reinvent the wheel, or in this case a [**hash table**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)?

CRC32 is for calculating checksums, it's not designed to be fast hash function, it's designed to detect errors (changes) in files. 
Four your needs, you might rather want to look at [**non-cryptographic hash functions**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions#Non-cryptographic_hash_functions).

Comment: or use embeddable search/DB engine which does all this plus has query interface with OR/AND etc.

Comment: Actually I'm using a distributed cache which has indexing capabilities. I load my Db records into the cache. When I add an entry into the cache I rather have to index an integer hash rather then the original string value. Much faster no?

Comment: Using Java but if I understand myString.hashCode() can have collisions?

Comment: any hash can have collisions.